# How to Fix a Scratched LCD Display?

Tags: laptop, lcd

I've got a killer laptop display - it's a Dell studio XPS 16 with the shiny, glossy display.

The problem is that there's a tiny little scratch in the middle of the screen, and I'm not sure if there's anything I can do about it. It's just really irritating, because it looks like something is on the screen.

Comment: Let me tell you how *not* to fix it (just in case you get such a crazy idea): A friend of a friend in college was a big car buff, and when he saw a scratch in his LCD monitor, he did the logical car buff thing: he sanded it. With sandpaper. Didn't work out so well.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Scratch-on-an-LCD-Screen

I am not sure I would endorse any of the first methods.  I personally would only trust a professional repair kit.  You really do not want to mess it up even worse by trying a cheap method. Depends on how much the monitor is worth and how much it is worth to you. I have an expensive monitor, so I wouldn't risk it with cheap methods.

Comment: Suggestion: Obtain used cheap monitor to practice repairs on.

Comment: Novus plastic polish (three step) which is mentioned in that link is great, but I've never used it on an LCD.

Comment: Decided to fly an R/C quad-copter in my office. Crashed it with my 27" DELL LCD leaving a very visible set of circular marks.. I took a small piece of Mr clean magic eraser, put a few water drops on it and gently used it on the screen.. Scratches gone!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and, in my opinion, best option is to just buy a new monitor, or see if Dell can fix the scratch for you (if the scratch is not covered under warranty, be prepared to cough up)

Common solutions to this problem are to:

- Using a dry, clean eraser from the end of a pencil, lightly rub over the scratch until is disappears. Although it may sound silly, it can work
- Fill the scratch with petroleum jelly.

A more drastic method is to replace the screen yourself. Check out [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Laptop+LCD+Screen+Replacement) for more help on that one.

Comment: It's a rather pricey laptop screen, can't buy a new one very easily.

Comment: I cannot believe that an answer with the ridiculous eraser and petroleum jelly "solutions" would get any upvotes.  They do NOT work, and the eraser makes things worse.